# NameError: name 'logging' is not defined

Tags: python

I am getting an error when trying to run a python script in Linux. I am trying to run a Firewall configuration converter I have dowloaded from here:

https://github.com/glennake/DirectFire_Converter
(converter.py file)

First I was getting an error related to logger, but after running a pip3 install logger it has been fixed. Now I am getting NameError: name 'logging' is not defined, despite of code looking good as far I know. For some reason, it looks like this line is not working:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

But I am seeing that all modules are being imported properly. Any idea about what is bringing the issue? Thanks.

---

full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "converter1.py", line 257, in <module>
    main(src_format=args.source, dst_format=args.destination, routing_info=args.routing)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traceback_with_variables/print.py", line 98, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "converter1.py", line 233, in main
    parsed_data = parse(
  File "converter1.py", line 107, in parse
    from DirectFire.Converter.parsers.ciscoasa_pre83 import parse
  File "/home/ubuntu/DirectFire_Converter/DirectFire/Converter/parsers/ciscoasa_pre83.py", line 23, in <module>
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
NameError: name 'logging' is not defined
```

Comment: `logging` is a built-in package. It does not need to be installed, but it has to be imported, what seems to be missing in this case.

Comment: Checking the code I realized that `logging` is imported. The error is somewhere else. Show us the full error traceback.

Comment: Thanks for answering but the import logging command is already set, and this is the reason because I do not know what is happening :-S. You can find the full error traceback in the main message. I have just added it. Thanks!

Comment: The last file given in the traceback has a bad import: `logger` vs. `logging`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import, add `import logging` at the top of your file

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to delete the virtual environment file -> `.venv` in python and create a new one with latest python version to fix the error. I kept getting this error when using aws boto3 SDK.